# Optimization of an ActiveRecord query to exclude certain items given two linked HABTM and has_many relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, query-optimization, activeadmin

I need to display only certain entries from one table in ActiveAdmin by means of a filter, which I implement as a select (dropdown) and whose code is in a Rails scope.
I'm having troubles in finding a pure SQL substitute in a Rails scope to the following condition.

I have the following models:

```rb
# app/models/score.rb

class Score < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :export_orders, join_table: :scores_export_orders
end

# app/models/export_order.rb

class ExportOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :scores, join_table: :scores_export_orders
  belongs_to :shop
end

# app/models/shop.rb

class Shop < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :export_orders
end
```

The filter lets you select a shop, so the relative code needs to return a `Score::ActiveRecord_Relation` in the scope.

The condition is: return all scores that haven't been exported to the selected shop, i.e. *all scores having none of their export orders with `shop` equal to the selected shop*.

As an example, imagine the following scenario:

```
[608, []]
[607, []]
[606, []]
[593, [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 1, 8, 8, 8, nil, nil, nil, nil, 8, 8]]
[586, []]
[585, []]
[372, [nil, nil, 2, nil, nil, nil, 8, 8, 8, nil]]
[157, [nil, 2, nil, nil, nil, 1]]
```

where on the left you have the score ids, and on the right an array of the shop ids of their export orders. To be clear, above is the result of `Score.all.map { |s| [s.id, s.export_orders.map{|o|o.shop_id}] }`.

So for example, the result of `Score.not_exported_to(2).ids` should be

```
[608, 607, 606, 593, 586, 585]
```

because none of the export orders of the scores (with these ids) has `2` in their shop ids.

---

Right now, I really can't think of an SQL way to write this. What I have up to now in my scope is:

```rb
# app/models/score.rb

  scope :not_exported_to, -> (input) {
    shop = Shop.find(input)
    export_orders = shop.export_orders
    already_exported_score_ids = export_orders.map { |o| o.scores.ids } .flatten.uniq
    where.not(id: already_exported_score_ids)
  }
```

This gives the right result, but is obviously very inefficient, since it uses a `map` on a dependent association (`Score`), which executes a select on the scores table repeated a number of times equal to `export_orders.count`. Imagine it being run on 1000+ export orders of a shop!

What I tried so far:

```sql
joins("INNER JOIN scores_export_orders ON scores.id = scores_export_orders.score_id INNER JOIN export_orders ON export_orders.id = scores_export_orders.export_order_id").distinct.where("export_orders.shop_id <> #{input}")
```

but this returns the wrong result.

I'm not so expert in SQL and I'm afraid I'd have to use some kind of nested queries, which I'm not really familiar with.

Comment: Try this - `Score.joins(export_orders: shops).where.not(export_orders: {shop_id: shop.id})`

Comment: @gautam that doesn't work for me. First, your code gives a `NameError` because `shops` is undefined, but even if I use `joins(export_orders: :shop)`, it does not produce the wanted result.

Comment: what is the result you are getting with the this query and what is it that you need?

Comment: I changed my question, edited the scope code (after realizing even what I wrote before was wrong) and added an example with a result. Your query returns `[593, 593, 593, 593, 593, 593, 372, 372, 372, 157]`, which is far from the result I wrote. Hope I've been clear enough in the question.

Comment: try this - `scope :not_exported_to, -> (shop_id) {
joins(:export_orders).where.not(export_orders: { shop_id: shop_id })
}`

Comment: @Gautam it does not work - result ids are `[593, 593, 593, 593, 593, 593, 593, 372, 372, 372, 157]`